# SSAS Moving Average / Rollup / Cumulative Periods

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, cube

Let's say we have the current situation in the `Cube Browser` for Working Days Analysis.

`Date8` it's part of the `DimDateBST` `Dimension` and it was created in format year-month-day and the `WD_Avg` is our interested measurement. The logic behind it's simple... If the day in month it's a working day then the value it's **1**. If there is no woking day it's **0**. If it's a half working day then it's **0,5**.

[image: Cube Browser]

We need to create a `calculated measure` to `Rollup` the measurement `WD_AVG` based on the type of day. The desired result would be then:

[image: Desired Result]

How would be that achievable? Is there any `MDX-function` that would work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by creating the following calculated measure:

```
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[WD_Cum]
    AS
      SUM({NULL:[Dim Date BST].[Dat Cal].CurrentMember}
         ,  [Measures].[WD_AVG])
    ;
```

`{NULL:xxx}` creates a set of everything before the xyz member, i.e. everything to Dat Cal...

[image: Result]